# Python "Can't Assign to Operator" Error using loop function

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment

I am attempting to run a loop to import several zipped text files into Pandas and create cross-tabulations.  The code is below:

```
def delta_calc(start_year,end_year):
for x in range(start_year, end_year+1,1):
    return
    "disposition"+x+"_24mo_df"=pd.read_table("path/lps_"+x+".txt",compression='gzip',sep='\t')
    "disposition"+x+"_24mo_df".sort(['loan_id','last_paid_interest_date'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)
    "disposition"+x+"_24mo_nodups_df"="disposition"+x+"_24mo_df".drop_duplicates('loan_id')
    "disposition"+x+"_24mo_crosstab"=pd.crosstab("disposition"+x+"_24mo_nodups_df".initial_investor_code,"disposition"+x+"_24mo_nodups_df".current_investor_code, margins=True)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
   File "<ipython-input-63-d662d71d1354>", line 4
           "disposition"+x+"_24mo_df"=pd.read_table("path/lps_"+x+".txt",compression='gzip'    ,sep='\t')
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message couldn't possibly clearer. What you're trying to do is `a+b = some_function()`. What should this be/do? Additionally, your syntax is off (`return \n ...\n...\n`)

Comment: Variable names are not strings and you cannot compose them the same way as you compose strings. "disposition"+x+"_24mo_df" is an expression, not a variable and cannot be assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of looks like a common beginner mistake of trying to dynamically generate variable names like `val_1`, `val_2`, ..., `val_N`, instead of using a list, or a bunch of lists in your case.

You can use `.append()` to add a new item to the back of a list, and index with `[-1]` to get the current last item in a list. The beginning would look something like this:

```
def delta_calc(start_year,end_year):
    disposition_24mo_df = []
    disposition_24mo_nodups_df = []
    disposition_24mo_crosstab = []
    for x in range(start_year, end_year+1):
        disposition_24mo_df.append(pd.read_table(...))
        disposition_24mo_df[-1].sort(...)
```

Though I haven't had any practical experience with pandas so this could be off-base.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning to an expression:

```
"disposition"+x+"_24mo_df"=pd.read_table("path/lps_"+x+".txt",compression='gzip',sep='\t')
```

Same problem with this:

```
"some string" + x + "another string" = some_code()
```

which is not valid.

Maybe that `=` sign is supposed to be something else?